# Не могу понять работает ли nginx или нет (ОС: Debian)

Tags: linux, node.js, nginx, debian

Настроил прокси- сервер на nginx, но не могу понять вообще работает ли потому что ничего не изменилось, файл access.log в /var/log/nginx пустой, захожу по адресу https://site.ru

```
server {
    # IP, который мы будем слушать
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  site.ru;

    keepalive_timeout    60;
    ssl_certificate      _address_/site.ru.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  _address_/site.ru.key;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers          "HIGH:!RC4:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH";
    add_header           Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=604800';

    location / {
        # IP и порт, на которых висит node.js
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Правильно ли я указываю proxy_pass, если запускаю node.js сервер на 3000 порту?

Код node сервера:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('Test');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000);

console.log('Server running at port 3000');
```

Comment: вы слушаете не IP 443, а порт 443.а это https трафик

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, да, мне нужно слушать https трафик и отвечать тем, что ответит node.js

Comment: Для начала стоит проверить dns

Comment: Ну и погасить сервер и проверить открывается ли сайт

Answer (score 0):

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_redirect    off;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    }
```

так должно быть правильнее

Comment: Сделал так, эффекта нет, node.js запущен на 3000 порту, но до него не доходит запрос почему- то видимо

Comment: Добавил код node сервера